# Good starting point for calling api in ionic framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic framework so i don't have much idea. I want to know that how do i call api using ionic in my app? please anybody have any idea then suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integrating a API Service with AngularJS in Ionic**

```
 angular.module('ionicApp', [])

 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('https://cors-test.appspot.com/test').then(function(resp) {
         console.log('Success', resp);
          // For JSON responses, resp.data contains the result
       }, function(err) {
         console.error('ERR', err);
         // err.status will contain the status code
       })
})
```

***[More...](http://www.gajotres.net/best-html5-mobile-app-frameworks-ionic-review/)***

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('ionicApp', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http({
       method: method,//GET/POST/DELETE
       url: url,
       data: data,//JSON DATA FOR POST
       dataType: 'json',
       headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
       }
       }).success(function (data) {//Success handling
            console.log(data);
       }).error(function (data, status) {//Error handling
            console.log(status + data);
       });
)}
```

Above method works for any type of HTTP(Get/Post/Delete/Put) request.

Regards